# Trouble setting up Ajax request/response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, datatables

I have a page that builds out a table.  Nothing else on that page but the table that is filled from a query.

I need to call this page through jQuery/ajax and somehow have it returned into this function.

Here is the jQuery function that needs to call the page and supply the return from the page into the sOut variable.

I am using DataTables.

```
/* Formatting function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>' + aData[1] + ' ' + aData[4] + '</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';

    return sOut;
}
```

I need sOut to somehow be changed so it = the call to the ajax page.

The path to the ajax page is. `"ajax/order_history_orderlines.asp"`

The ajax page is expecting one parameter to be sent over and that is aData[1] which will supply the orderID.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make sOut grab the ajax page?

Better example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut = 'ajax/order_history_orderlines.asp?orderid=' + aData[1];

    return sOut;
}
```

Comment: You aren't making an ajax request.  You need to make an asynchronous call over the network.  Look into a library like jQuery (you will need to download and include it on your page).  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @JustinThomas that was the point of the question.  Help in making the Ajax request...  Everything is setup in place except the request.  Will look over your link.

Comment: I know, but the whole structure/setup is incorrect.  Ajax requests don't return values.  It's a little unclear what you are trying to do...  Is sOut supposed to be returned from the ajax/order_history_orderlines?  Or what?  It looks like you are trying to format sOut from some other data here.

Comment: sOut is supposed to = what ajax/order_history_orderlines.asp gives it.  Which is nothing but a copy of the table above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/order_history_orderlines.asp?orderid=' + aData[1],
  success: function(data) {
  /* do something with your data here */
  }
});
```

Comment: I got it to work, however there is something else going on.  The ajax request works, returns the data I am looking for.  It just doesn't update my existing table which I thought it would do.  If I write out sOut like in the original post with <table> it correctly adds the data so when I click details it expands the row.  But when I turn it into an Ajax request clicking details just expands a blank row.  I must be missing something. =(

Comment: Use console.log(data); to see what the structure of the data is.  Sometimes it's XML, or Text, or maybe JSON data.  You maybe have to select what parts of the data object you want.

Comment: It returns this as responseText `" <!-- Teplate for orderlines found in rs Record Set --> <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 50px;"> <tr> <td> Quantity: </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> Description: </td> <td> 48 Cans of Pur3x Revolution </td> </tr> </table> "`

Comment: Now you just have to figure out where to put it.  Assume you had a HTML tag called <p id="my_table"></p>  You'd do $('#my_table').html(data);